# What Germanic language is the most understandable for the native English speakers?

Tags: germanic-languages

What Germanic language is the most understandable for the native English speakers?

Comment: I'm not sure how on-topic this question actually is, but anyway, I *hear* it's Frisian. Of course, hearsay is not a proper answer.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Frisian is commonly considered the [closest to English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113646) but which is most "understandable" is likely to be dependent on the listener, leaving aside the matter of whether Scots and Fingallian and others should be classified as distinct languages or as dialects.

Comment: I would say that no Germanic language is particularly understandable to the average native English speaker.

Comment: This question has been asked before, and has been answered: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113646/why-is-it-that-frisian-is-considered-the-closest-related-language-to-english

Comment: Frankly (pun intended), either French or Spanish is easier to read than German because of the large overlap in educated vocabulary (and exposure in the US).

Comment: Also, once a language gets just over the threshold of unintelligibility, they're all as ununderstandable as the other.

Comment: Oh. I forgot Scots. That is the most understandable of ununderstandable languages.